# How can I merge register/logon from 3 scripts (databases) into one form -for one userdashboard?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, forms

I am pretty new at building sites have tried to build my 3 scripts so my users only need to register with one registry form and login with one logon form, in order to get access to use all 3 "features" scripts with a logon.

The plan is that I will make a member / user dashboard where the three websites can be used from.

Right now the three websites made as http://e-meditecs.com/art, /adz and /class. Each of the websites have their own register and login forms, thus also each have their own SQL database.

I have a "front page e-mediatecs . com where I think the Register and Logon shape to be placed.

I is completely solid and have made many google searches, now seemed just that I only become more confused.

Hope that the issue is understandable.

Comment: are you sure you want to say databases, instead of tables?

Comment: I agree with @mouse, normally you create a user table and you can use the same login structure over the 3 locations. and inside the table you can eventfully make simple access role for each user that allow to use art adz and class

Comment: could you illustrate your question with some php code of login page you use?